# Seeing difference when run jmx from Java application and GUI mode

Tags: jmeter

My Java pom.xml has these dependencies:

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_core</artifactId>
            <version>5.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

and in my jmx file -> jsr223 assertion I have this simple function:

```
log.info(prev.getResponseDataAsString())
```

When I run from GUI mode I am able to see the complete response logged in the console, but when my Java application executes the same jmx, I got:

```
2018/10/25 20:50:53,576 12050 [INFO  ] [Thread Group 1-1] (?:?) – 
${__FileToString(${inputFilePath},,)}
```

Is this because I miss some dependencies in my pom.xml? Since it always return

> ${__FileToString(${inputFilePath},,)}

instead of the actual response which cause I am not able to continue the rest of the test. Rest of stuff all depends on this result. This function comes from the ***body data*** of the HTTP Request sampler!!!!!! If I give actual body there then I am able to run the jmx...... Any idea how to deal with this dynamic body data?

**UPDATE 1**
I found the solution! Instead directly use the `${__FileToString(${inputFilePath},,)}` in the body data of HTTP Request Sampler, I can just create one more JSR223 Sampler above the HTTP Request Sampler and in this sampler, I can just do:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils
log.info("--------------------------------------- "+ '${inputFilePath}')
String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File('${inputFilePath}'))

vars.put("reqBody", content)
```

and in the body data of HTTP Request Sampler, I will do `${reqBody}`. That's it!

Comment: Instead of update 1 you can answer your own question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were missing dependency :

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jmeter</groupId>
        <artifactId>ApacheJMeter_functions</artifactId>
        <version>5.0</version>
    </dependency>
```